# Passing multiple files as arguments in Bash Scripting and save their content in two arrays

Tags: bash, shell

I've tried to write a script which can get multiple files as inputs. Every line of the file has this form "num1:num2" and i want to save num1 and num2 in two different arrays and then to calculate the sums.

```
#!/bin/bash

args=("$@")
declare -a X
declare -a Y
for ((i=0; i<=${#args}; i++)) do
  input="${args[$i]}"

let  j=0
while  IFS=: read x y
  do
   X+=("$x")
   Y+=("$y")
   let j=j+1
 done < "$input"
  sumx=0
  sumx2=0
  sumy=0
  a=0
  sumxy=0
  b=0
  err=0
  for ((k=0; k<j; k++)) do
    sumx=  $(echo "scale=3; sumx + X[$k]" | bc -l)
    sumx2= $(echo "scale=3;sumx2 + X[$k]^2" | bc -l)
    sumy=  $(echo "scale=3;sumy + Y[$k]" | bc -l)
    sumxy=  $(echo "scale=3;sumxy + X[$k]*Y[$k]" | bc -l)
  done
  echo "$sumx"
done
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: (standard_in) 1: syntax error

Answer (score 2):

`awk` to the rescue!

since you didn't post any sample input, let's create some

```
$ seq 10 | paste -d: - - | tee file1 file2

$ head file{1,2}
==> file1 <==
1:2
3:4
5:6
7:8
9:10

==> file2 <==
1:2
3:4
5:6
7:8
9:10
```

Easy to add the corresponding fields with `awk`.

```
$ awk -F: '{sum1+=$1; sum2+=$2} END{print sum1,sum2}' file{1,2}

50 60
```

or, add the other computations

```
$ awk -F: '{sum1+=$1; sum2+=$2; sumsq1+=$1^2; sum12+=$1*$2} 
       END {print sum1,sum2,sumsq1,sum12}' file{1,2}

50 60 330 380
```

Comment: The question isn't entirely clear, but I think the goal was to print separate totals for each file. If this is right, it can be done in pure `awk`, but it's probably easier to wrap `awk` in a shell loop: `for input in "$@"; do awk -F: '...' "$input"; done`

Answer (score 1):

@karakfa has already shown a better way to do this in `awk`; I'd like to take a stab at fixing the bash version. The primary problem is some basic syntax mistakes:

First, in the loop:

```
for ((i=0; i<=${#args}; i++)) do
```

`${#args}` doesn't get the number of elements in the array, it gets the length (in characters) of the first element of the array. You want `${#args[@]}` instead. Or better yet, in don't iterate over the array indexes at all, just iterate over the array elements directly:

```
for input in "${args[@]}"; do
```

Second and third, in the calculation lines like

```
sumx=  $(echo "scale=3; sumx + X[$k]" | bc -l)
```

...you can't put spaces after the `=` sign (they change the meaning of the command *completely*), and also the variable references need `$` (and `${}` for the array element) to tell the shell to substitute them:

```
sumx=$(echo "scale=3; $sumx + ${X[$k]}" | bc -l)
```

This is what was causing the error messages you got. `bc` has no idea about shell variables; it will've just treated `sumx` as an uninitialized `bc` variable, but `X[1]` is invalid `bc` syntax (note that `$k` *will* have been substituted).

If you were actually doing this in the shell (rather than `awk`), I'd also suggest simplifying it by removing the arrays. There's no point in reading the files' contents into an array and then iterating over the array when you can just compute as you read:

```
while IFS=: read x y; do
    sumx=$(echo "scale=3; $sumx + $x" | bc -l)
    sumx2=$(echo "scale=3; $sumx2 + $x^2" | bc -l)
    sumy=$(echo "scale=3; $sumy + $y" | bc -l)
    sumxy=$(echo "scale=3; $sumxy + $x*$y" | bc -l)
done < "$input"
```